# Help needed in configuring audio drivers

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My alsa conf file is as follows: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b419e3e848cf45cc1d947da0596ee63ea7f310e0

After many many attempts, this is what I've ended up with. The realtek audio drivers from their site have been no help. Attached screenshots of sound, pulse audio. Would appreciate the help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr5nq.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e051r.png

Comment: Also, aplay -l gives the following output:    aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

Comment: Remove those Realtek drivers. (This might require reinstalling or repairing the kernel package.)

Comment: Try dkms Alsa driver , see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Comment: Tried both, neither helps.